# Saving Range Selection as PDF on Mac

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to try and export a specific selection as a one-page PDF. I was able to grant access but I can't seem to be able to export the selection as a PDF. I get a 1004 error. Any advice?

```
Sub PrintTest()

    ChDir "/Users/Mr_Madoff/Desktop/"

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F53").Select

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
        "/Users/Mr_Madoff/Desktop/Book1.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        False

End Sub
```